# Azure Timer Trigger Function Fails protobuf Import

Tags: python, azure, function, azure-functions

I have created a new Timer Trigger function in visual studio code using a Python 3.6 environment. Without changing any settings or code, running project produces following error message.

```
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM] Traceback (most recent call last):
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6/WINDOWS/X64/worker.py", line 59, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from azure_functions_worker import main
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\main.py", line 7, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from . import dispatcher
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\dispatcher.py", line 19, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from . import bindings
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\bindings\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from .meta import check_input_type_annotation
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\bindings\meta.py", line 4, in
<module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from .. import protos
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\protos\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from .FunctionRpc_pb2_grpc import (  # NoQA
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\protos\FunctionRpc_pb2_grpc.py", line 4, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from azure_functions_worker.protos import FunctionRpc_pb2 as azure__functions__worker_dot_protos_dot_FunctionRpc__pb2
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM] Starting worker process:python  "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6/WINDOWS/X64/worker.py" --host 127.0.0.1
--port 54996 --workerId 0f5d579f-d4c8-4141-82a2-f699d309b625 --requestId fc901970-1b5d-4a13-945f-c61c5323badf --grpcMaxMessageLength 134217728
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "C:\Users\murf\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\WINDOWS\X64\azure_functions_worker\protos\FunctionRpc_pb2.py", line 7, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]   File "c:\users\murf\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\workers\python\3.6\windows\x64\google\protobuf\descriptor.py", line 47, in <module>
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM]     from google.protobuf.pyext import _message
[1/24/2020 10:08:02 PM] ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

This import section is the last one in which _message is unable to be imported. This file is not present with the pip installation of protobuf (versions 3.6.0 and all later versions, including the latest version). The previous fix I have found online was to install version 3.6.0, but this does not solve the issue.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!